# how to stop krisp.ai app from starting on boot

Tags: startup

The Krisp app (a noise filter for skype calls) starts automatically on boot, and even if I remove it from the list of startup items, I keep finding it there.

This is annoying and intrusive. I like the app and I need it, so I won't uninstall it just yet, but I'd like it to start when I want, not when it wants.

Comment: Run etrecheck.com and see if you can find where the app is started.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It sounds like there's a `launchd` service (daemon) running that checks to make sure it's in your startup items (Spotify has something similar).  Given that it's a 3rd party *paid* app (not affiliated with Skype or Apple/macOS) , have you contacted their support offering to see why they do this and if there's a setting to disable it?  What did they advise?

Answer (score 1):

Open System Preferences.
Go to Users & Groups.
Choose your nickname on the left.
Choose the Login items tab.
Check startup programs you want to remove.
Press the “–” sign below.
You're done.

Comment: Is this a general advice or does it solve the problem the OP has with a specific application?

Comment: At the beginning of the question I say that this doesn’t work.

Comment: @Ziofil hmm that's weird, it did work for me tho! You can try contacting their support team I guess.

Comment: @nohillside yes you can use these steps to remove any application from startup!

Comment: Not if the application autostarts by other means :-)

Comment: If you reboot it will be there again